# Need to Update VolumeControl of J2ME application using Device Volume Control Keys

Tags: java-me, media-player

In J2ME how to detect Device Volume Control key is pressed in application?. I tried `keyPressed()`, but it not invoked when Device Volume Control Key is Pressed.

Comment: where you are using keyPressed() method ? in Form or in Canvas ?

Comment: currently i am using keyPressed() of the Form.as user change the Volume using Device Volume control keys it should reflects to Media Player Volume control

Answer (score 0):

you can not get `keyPressed();` event in the `Form`. You can add two `Command` Button to increase or decrease the volume.

Comment: using two Button it worked fine.but i want to handle the Device Volume control key and map that in the Mediaplayer VolumeControl.as user change volume control using the Device it should update the image of volume control

Comment: Ok Megha,try this, make one canvas application and try to see in s.o.p. what value you get when are you pressing volume control keys.

Comment: in my project structure i can not make it canvas.it is structured in this way only.any how i have to find method to get the event of Device volume control

Comment: I am just telling you to make another canvas application and see what numeric values you are getting for those volume control key. Once you get those values, you may use it in normal Command Listener. So this way it can help you out.

Comment: ok get you point.now make a new application and check the keycode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5045/discussion-between-megha-and-lucifer)